# Looping through nested array of objects, matching to another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, javascript-objects

I am new to Javascript and am trying to loop through one nested array of objects, and filtering a second array of objects based on properties of the first.

Here are both arrays' structures:

```
const displayArr = {
   sections: {
      section_1: [
        {
          style: "single_select_cmp",
          definition: {
            table_name: "table_1",
            field_name: "organization",
          }
        },
      ],
      section_2: [
        {
          style: "single_select_cmp",
          definition: {
            table_name: "table_1",
            field_name: "title",
          }
        },
      ]
   }
};

const schemaArr = [
  {
    table_1: {
      columns: [
        {
          description: "Tracking Number Desc",
          display_name: "Tracking Number",
          display_type: "number",
          field: "tracking_number",
          type: "int"
        },
        {
          description: "Title Desc",
          display_name: "Title",
          display_type: "multiple lines of text",
          field: "title",
          type: "text"
        },
        {
          description: "Description Desc",
          display_name: "Description",
          display_type: "multiple lines of text",
          field: "description",
          type: "text"
        },
        {
          description: "Organization Desc",
          display_name: "Organization",
          display_type: "single line of text",
          field: "organization",
          type: "text"
        }
     ]
   }
 },
 {
  table_2: { columns: [ {...}, {...} ] }
 },
 {
  table_3: { columns: [ {...}, {...} ] }
 }
 ...
]
```

I am trying to filter `schemaArr` by `table_name` and `field_name` in the `displayArr`. When there is a match, I would like to supply the `description` and `display_name` to the displayArr. For example:

```
const displayArr = {
   sections: {
      section_1: [
        {
          style: "single_select_cmp",
          definition: {
            table_name: "table_1",
            field_name: "organization",
            description: "Organization Description", //***
            display_name: "Organization" //***
          }
        },
      ],
      section_2: [
        {
          style: "single_select_cmp",
          definition: {
            table_name: "table_1",
            field_name: "title",
            description: "Title Description", //***
            display_name: "Title" //***
          }
        },
      ]
   }
};
```

In this example, I am only pulling from `table_1`, however there may be any number of tables referenced in `displayArr`.

To me, given these objects are nested, this is a more complex mapping/filtering situation. I'm wondering how to correctly and efficiently leverage map, filter, and/or forEach.

Thank you in advance for your help! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) can be used to get values of `displayArr` object and [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can be used to iterate on it.

[find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method can be used to find the table with `table_name` in `schemaArr`. If table exists, then [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method can be used again to find the column with item's `field_name`.

Then `displayArr` object's definition item can be updated with this found column values.

```
Object.values(displayArr.sections).forEach(section => {
  section.forEach(item => {
    let table = schemaArr.find(table => table[item.definition.table_name]);

    if (table) {
      // Find column by field_name.
      let obj = table[item.definition.table_name].columns.find(column => column.field === item.definition.field_name);           

      if (obj) {
        // Update definition.
        item.definition.description = obj.description;
        item.definition.display_name = obj.display_name;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: this makes perfect sense. I realized I said schemaArr was an object, but really it is an array of table objects. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @BWeb303 - No problem, we can use `find()` method to find the table in the array. But `schemaArr` in your edited question isn't valid, arrays can't have property names. Do you have something like `schemaArr = [{table_1: ...}, {table_2: ...}, ...]` instead?

Comment: argh.. you're absolutely right. My apologies. The client's data is structured as follows: ```schemaArr = [ {table_1: { columns: [ {...}, {...} ] } }, {table_2:....} ]```. Certainly not best practice, but that is what I'm working with. I've updated my question to reflect the true schema structure. This would likely change how ```table``` is being set in your response.

Comment: @BWeb303 - No problem. I thought so. See my edited answer. Also, is `displayArr` an object or an array? Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: In reality I'm actually just calling ```sections``` as is. I'm not stuffing ```sections``` into ```displayArr``` or some other object. So I think I would do ```Object.values(sections)``` instead. Really sorry for all the errors on my part. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @BWeb303 - Yes, that's what you would do then. No problem at all.

Comment: worked perfectly. Only change I had to make was ```let obj = table[item.definition.table_name].columns.find...```. Thanks again, really huge help.

Comment: Yep, that's right @BWeb303. I'm glad you figured it out.